# Enumeration trouble: redeclared as different kind of symbol

Tags: c++, enumeration

I am writing a program that is supposed to help me learn about enumeration data types in C++. The current trouble is that the compiler doesn't like my enum usage when trying to use the new data type as I would other data types. I am getting the error "redeclared as different kind of symbol" when compiling my trangleShape function. Take a look at the relevant code. Any insight is appreciated! Thanks!

(All functions are their own .cpp files.)

**header file**

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

enum triangleType {noTriangle, scalene, isoceles, equilateral};

//prototypes
void extern input(float&, float&, float&);
triangleType extern triangleShape(float, float, float);
/*void extern output (float, float, float);*/
void extern myLabel(const char *, const char *);



#endif // HEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

**main function**

```
//8.1 main
// this progam...

#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    float sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3;
    char response;


     do //main loop
      {
           input (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3);
           triangleShape (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3);
           //output (sideLength1, sideLength2, sideLength3);
           cout << "\nAny more triangles to analyze? (y,n) ";
           cin >> response;
      }
    while (response == 'Y' || response == 'y');

    myLabel ("8.1", "2/11/2011");

    return 0;
}
```

**triangleShape shape**

```
# include "header.h"

triangleType triangleShape(sideLenght1, sideLength2, sideLength3)
{
    triangleType triangle;
    return triangle;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with enums. The problem line is this line in your triangleShape definition:

```
triangleType triangleShape(sideLenght1, sideLength2, sideLength3)
```

You're missing the types for your parameters and some compilers such as gcc default to `int` (although this isn't standard behaviour so you should never rely on it). Since the function definition uses `float`s the compiler sees it as redeclaring it differently. You should use specify `float`s in the implementation:

```
triangleType triangleShape(float sideLenght1, float sideLength2, float sideLength3)
```